# Excel VLookup #NV error

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to make a VLookup in Excel but I get everytime a #NV error.

This is table `EVENTS`:

[image: EVENTS]

This is table `TRACK`:

[image: TRACK]

the formula on field F2 in table EVENTS is

```
=SVERWEIS(E2;TRACKS!$A$2:$B$52;1;FALSCH)
```

`SVERWEIS` is the word for `VLOOKUP` in the German version. `FALSCH` means wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the columns in `TRACKS` around.

`VLOOKUP` bases it's lookup on the first column, so in your case, it's looking through column `A` (1, 2, 3, etc.)

If you want your `VLOOKUP` to be based on the text, it needs to be in `A` instead.

i.e.

```
  | A      | B       |
----------------------
1 | TEXT   | VLOOKUP |
2 | Text1  | 1       |
3 | Text2  | 2       |
etc...
```

Then your function will be:

```
=SVERWEIS(E2;TRACKS!$A$2:$B$52;2;FALSCH)
```

Switching out the third argument because you now want the value from the second column

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP` compares the values in the first column of your reference target, you have your target values in the second.

Just swap `VLOOKUP` and the `TEXT` columns on your *TRACKS* sheet and it will work just fine.

Comment: @MarekStejskal: z toho si Marku nic nedelej. Tve reseni fungovalo a to je to hlavni.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, VLOOKUP (SVERWEIS) can only look to its right to find a value to correspond with a value in the left hand columns of a table. The INDEX/MATCH combination is more flexible in this respect so if not to rearrange your columns I would suggest something like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,B:B,0))
```

where TRACK is assumed to be in ColumnsA:B. Converting to German, perhaps:

```
=INDEX(TRACKS!A:A;VERGLEICH(E2;TRACKS!B:B;0))
```